# How to provoke apport dialog for testing?

Tags: apport, testing

I'm investigating [apport issue 1505368](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/1505368) and would like to reproduce the situation after an application crash where the `apport` dialog pops up asks to restart or close the crashed application (and optionally to open a bug report which isn't working in my case).

What's the easiest way to achieve this situation? Is there a test segmentation fault package which I can install? Do I have to produce a simple C program myself (e.g. with `int a = *((int*)1)`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apport` seems to detect failure of interpreters (e.g. `python3`) due to syntax errors if the script doesn't match the interpreters language (e.g `mysql-workbench`), i.e. `` python3 `which mysql-workbench` `` triggers `apport` to suggest reporting a bug.